# How to assign weight for a word?

Tags: r

I have a list of words for four categories. There are 10 words for each category. Now I want to assign a weight for each word in the list. For example if one category has words:

```
 disease
 fall
 have
 ventilator
 tumour
 country
 sewing
 demo
 precaution
 analysis
```

Now for each of these words I want to give a weight. For example disease should be given weight 1(by dividing 10 by 10), fall should be given weight 0.9 (by dividing 9 by 10), have should be given 0.8 and so on. How to write this code in R? Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

I want my output to be:

```
Death               Malfunction         Weight
distance             malformed             1
fall                 unformed             0.9
have                 intensive            0.8
ventilator           malfunctioned        0.7
tumour               front                0.6
country              icu                  0.5
sewing               injury               0.4
demo                 care                 0.3
precaution           disease              0.2
analysis             diagnosis            0.1
```

Comment: Perhaps `(nrow(df):1)/nrow(df)` Do you have a `category` column?.  If there is a category column `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, wt:=(.N:1)/.N , by = category]`

Comment: Yes I have four categories

Comment: If it is a category column, the data.table method should work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I am not able to find the correct answer.

Comment: Add a `dput` of a sample of your table and your expected output, else people will only be able to guess what you're asking for.

Comment: I have edited my question with what is my expected output

Comment: Based on the input dataset, `df$Weight <- (nrow(df):1)/nrow(df)`

Comment: Thanks it works. How can I run it for two categories

Comment: I have edited this question with two classes. How can I assign weight to this two classes separately? Can anyone post an answer for this?